# Can Ruby import a .NET dll?

Tags: .net, windows, ruby, com, dll

I am interested in using/learning RoR in a project where I have to use a .NET dll. Is Ruby capable of importing a .NET dll?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

While IronRuby will make short work of talking to your .NET dll (it'll be literally no code at all), it was abandoned by microsoft, and it never got a large enough open source community to keep it going after that event. I wouldn't recommend it these days

Regarding the COM solution, this may actually be a good way to go.

You don't need the RubyCOM library - that lets other COM objects call into ruby code. To load COM objects from ruby, you just need the `win32ole` library, which comes as part of the standard library on windows ruby.

Whether or not you can load the dll from COM will depend if the .NET dll was built to be 'Com Visible'.
The .NET framework defines a `ComVisibleAttribute`, which can be applied to either an entire assembly, or specific classes within an assembly. If it is set to true for either the whole assembly, or any classes, then the dll will already be callable from COM without any wrapper code.

Here's a test I did.

Create a new .NET dll project (class library). Here's an example class I used:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ComLib
{
    public class LogWriter
    {
        public void WriteLine( string line )
        {
            using( var log = new StreamWriter( File.OpenWrite( @"c:\log.file" ) ) )
            {
                log.WriteLine( line );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, under the visual studio project, there is a directory called `Properties` which contains `AssemblyInfo.cs`. In this file, there will be the following

```
[assembly: ComVisible( false )]
```

Change the false to true. If you don't want *every class* in the assembly exposed to COM, then you can leave it set to false in `AssemblyInfo.cs` and instead put it above each class you want to expose, like this:

```
[ComVisible( true )]
public class LogWriter ....
```

Now right click on the dll project itself, and from the popup menu, select 'properties'. In the list of sections, choose `Build`

Scroll down, and tick the 'Register for COM interop' checkbox. Now when you compile this DLL, visual studio will do the neccessary stuff to load the COM information into the registry. Note if you're on vista you need to run VS as an administrator for this to work.

Now that this is done, recompile your dll, and then create a new ruby file.

In this ruby file, do this:

```
require 'win32ole'

lib = WIN32OLE.new('[Solution name].ComLib.LogWriter')
lib.WriteLine('calling .net from ruby via COM, hooray!')
```

Where [Solution name] is to be replaced by the name of the solution you just created (default: "ClassLibrary1")

Ruby that ruby file, and presto! you should see that the text gets written to `c:\log.file`.

One problem with this solution is that it requires that the .NET dll is already Com Visible, or if it's not, you have the ability to recompile it. If neither of these things are true, then you may have to look at other options.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the comVisible property of dll to see if I can implement this solution.

Comment: Using above code i am accessing .Net dll code and doing great but i want to know how to close this task... if i want to use this frequently.... if i use same code i frequently means will not run it again ... Is there any way to close /kill object?

Comment: What do you mean by kill the object? The .NET runtime manages the lifetime of COM objects for you. When the garbage collector runs it will check and see if any .NET code is referencing the COM object, and if not, it will clean it up. If .NET code *is* still referencing it, then to clean it up would cause an error.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but checking the box to "Register for COM interop", will that only work on the box on which it was compiled or will I have to register it on the box I intend to use it.

Comment: @OrionEdwards I know it's an old question but this could really save my day, after doing this registration, i created a new ruby file, saved it on my desktop and ruby'd it. i got this error:
`initialize': unknown OLE server:
Any idea on what might i be doing wrong?

Comment: How to register this dll properly?

Answer (score 4):

You can also write a native -> C# wrapper DLL using managed C++

Export all the functions you want as C calls in the DLL, e.g.

```
extern "C" __declspec ( dllexport ) void CallManagedMethod() {
   Something^ myManagedObject ...
}
```

Then use FFI to call that DLL from Ruby
https://github.com/ffi/ffi

Comment: Hi!
I know it's been a while, but:
I've attempted this approach and everything goes smooth until the C++ wrapper DLL references .Net DLL method at runtime. Then I get "Could not load file or assembly" exception regarding .Net DLL. Any ideas why?
(Both DLL's are under the same folder as ruby script which exports and calls C++ function. .Net DLL call works OK if called from the C++ console application from the same folder.)

Comment: I don't know, sorry @VitaliyProkopenko. It worked for me back in 2011. I think that "Could not load file or assembly" can occur for many different reasons and you'll need to turn on extra diagnostic info. Perhaps raise a new question with more details? GL

Comment: Thanks, @Rich. Actually already opened one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67229089/ruby-ffi-call-of-c-function-fails-at-script-execution-time-when-referencing-me)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use 'normal' ruby (since I dont think IronRuby fully runs RoR yet) you might be able to go via COM - ie

```
"Your Ruby Code" -> RubyCOM -> "COM-Callable Wrappers" -> "Your .NET objects"
```

[RubyCom](http://www.geocities.com/masonralph/rubycomdoc.html)

That's a bit convoluted though.

*Edit: better COM-based option elsewhere in the answers*

Answer (score 1):

Another thing - it might be better to think about it more from a Service-Oriented Architecture point. Can you take that .NET DLL and expose it as a service?

Behind the scenes, you can write Ruby modules in C, so you can always write an interop to do what you need. It will limit your deployment to Windows platforms, though (I haven't tried Ruby->Interop->Mono)

Here's a presentation I gave a couple of years back called [Ruby for C# Developers](http://www.cornetdesign.com/files/RubyCSharpStlCodeCamp.ppt). It's a little dated (It was before John Lam's project got folded into IronRuby), but might help a little.

Comment: Expose the .NET dll as a SOA service is a way to go, but i'll have to check the security issues of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IronRuby (Ruby implementation built on .Net) then it should be able to.  If you're already using .Net and want to try out Ruby then you might want to look into IronRuby.

Outside of IronRuby I'm not sure.  I haven't used Ruby myself, so I don't know what kinds of things it's capable of.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a dead project AFAIK, you may find the previous [RubyCLR project](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubyclr/) by John Lam (who is now in charge of IronRuby) an interesting one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in ASP.NET MVC with IronRuby together, You may find yourself to check out this source code from Jimmy - http://github.com/jschementi/ironrubymvc/tree/master

Enjoy!