# Call .NET dll via Google SketchUp Ruby Script

Tags: .net, ruby, sketchup

Is it possible, and does anyone have an example of how you might call upon a .NET dll from within Google SketchUp Ruby interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Ruby import a .NET dll ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265879/can-ruby-import-a-net-dll)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate, the other topic is about ruby in general. This is about the Google SketchUp Ruby script API, specificly, and whats capable from withine that running environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There are two ways. 
1. Build a ruby extension using C++/cli to call .NET stuff.
2. Build a ruby extension directly using c#, then you can easy call any .NET stuff.
You can find a simple example about build ruby extension using c# here https://bitbucket.org/icehuli/sucsexttutorial/wiki/Home