# Attach/call DLL files from ruby on rails

Tags: c#, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dllimport

I have SDK which exist on DLL files i need to attach those file with my ruby project and call dll files directly from ruby on rails web application.

I read about win32ole and ffi but i'm still confused.

I want to call DLL file directly from ROR web application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a simple c# dll and access it from ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366491/creating-a-simple-c-sharp-dll-and-access-it-from-ruby)

Comment: thanks....... but i have ZK40 Bio-metric attendance machine, which SDK have DLL file and i want to integrate SDK with my rails application.

Comment: Unless these DLLs have been written in a way that is accessible (e.g. COM), then you will either have to wrap the C# dll in another C# dll that exposes the functions via COM, or modify the original C# library to expose it.  The answer I linked to shows how to do it.

Comment: thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Kindly confirm me, i have also same sdk in .so format and im using ubuntu then still i have to use Win32API ?