# ruby WIN32OLE c# dll custom event listening

Tags: c#, ruby, events, win32ole

I have found this nice tutorial on connecting to a c# dll from Ruby:
[Can Ruby import a .NET dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265879/can-ruby-import-a-net-dll)
This works great for Ruby=>C# but not for c#=>Ruby.
Now I was thinking to work with some custom events to which Ruby can hook up.
I followed example A from this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx to create a custom event.

Now is the question, how do i link with this event from ruby?
In excel i would do:

```
xl_workbook_events = WIN32OLE_EVENT.new(xl_book, 'WorkbookEvents')
xl_workbook_events.on_event('SheetSelectionChange') do
    # do something when the selection has changed.
end#do
```

But, for a custom c# event, i have no idea..
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So, To make a com accessible DLL in C#: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23355/Callback-Functions-and-NET-C-COM-Components

To bind to the events from ruby:

```
require 'win32ole’
ole_connection = WIN32OLE.new(“YourNameSpace.YourClassName”)
event = WIN32OLE_EVENT.new(ole_connection)
event.on_event(‘NameOfYourEvent’) do |args| # NameOfYourEvent should be specified in 'CallBackEventInterface' from the example, like: 'TheEvent'. when using that event, arg should containt 'string msg'
    # do some work
    puts args.to_s
end#do
```